# Error while creating mount source path when running dockerized .NET core app

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-compose

1. I've created a .NET core web app from VS2017
2. Added docker support
3. Run via docker compose from VS

Received this error

```
MSB4018 The "PrepareForLaunch" task failed unexpectedly.
Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.CommandLineClientException: Creating network "dockercompose3401809455_default" with the default driver
Building webapplication1
Creating dockercompose3401809455_webapplication1_1
ERROR: for webapplication1  Cannot start service webapplication1: error while creating mount source path '/C/Users/admin/clrdbg': mkdir /C/Users/admin/clrdbg: permission denied
Encountered errors while bringing up the project..
```

I have

1. Enabled sharing on my C:\
2. Checked C:\ in docker's sharing settings

What else am I missing?

Here's the docker compose yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  webapplication1:
    image: webapplication1:dev
    build:
      args:
        source: ${DOCKER_BUILD_SOURCE}
    environment:
      - DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1
    volumes:
      - ./WebApplication1:/app
      - ~/.nuget/packages:/root/.nuget/packages:ro
      - ~/clrdbg:/clrdbg:ro
    entrypoint: tail -f /dev/null
    labels:
      - "com.microsoft.visualstudio.targetoperatingsystem=linux"
```

Comment: Are you running VS as a administrator? It looks like it's failing on permissions for a particular directory. Also what is the result of  `docker version`

Comment: Yes, VS is ran with elevated permissions. Docker version is 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e

Comment: Are you on Windows 10 pro? using Docker for Windows or Docker Toolbox? If you're using Docker for Windows make sure to have Linux containers selected.

Comment: Yes, I'm on Win10 Pro, using Docker for Windows. Where do I change that setting?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#switch-between-windows-and-linux-containers

Comment: It's already set to Linux. Are there any other diagnostics test I could run to identify the cause of this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145079/discussion-between-null-reference-and-mano-marks).

Answer (score 6):

Do you login to Windows using corporate/domain credentials? If so, you may need to configure Docker For Windows to access your Shared Drives under a newly created local account, as outlined in [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stevelasker/2016/06/14/configuring-docker-for-windows-volumes/):

1. Create a new local user via the "**Add, Edit or Remove Other People**" tool in Windows (be sure to select "**I don't have this person's information**" and then "**Add a user without a Microsoft account**")
2. Add this user to the **Local Administrators** group.

   - Check the below edit for alternatives to the following steps
3. Sign in as the new user by doing **CTRL + ALT + DEL** and selecting **Switch Users**
4. Navigate to **C:\Users\joe.blogs** (or whatever your regular user account is) and be sure to click **Continue** on any permissions windows that popup
5. Sign out of this session and log back in as your regular user
6. Rebuild the project via VS2017
7. ???
8. Profit (hopefully)

The part that had me stuck for ages was that I didn't realise I had to login as the user and manually click the "Continue" button on the permissions window for my other user account

---

**EDIT**

Instead of faffing around with **"Switch Users"**, you can also try going to **C:\Users** while logged into your regular user account, right clicking **your** user account and then selecting **"Give Access To"**. Add your local account as a user with access.

Comment: this is the answer if you are logging in with an enterprise/office365 account. thanks ian. this helped me out in a big way...